# Create next/back button for views

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently learning angular and I want to create next/back button for showing different views.

I have a *template* called `example.html`

```
<h1>{{ message }}</h1>
```

that is used by multiple controllers:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/home.html'
        }).
        when('/first', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/example.html',
            controller  : 'firstController'
        }).
        when('/second', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/example.html',
            controller  : 'secondController'
        }).
        when('/third', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/example.html',
            controller  : 'thirdController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

And I have a `header.html` that it's included in my `index.html`:

```
<a href="" data-ng-click="goBack()"> Next </a>
<a href="" data-ng-click="goNext()"> Back </a>
```

And this are the controllers:

```
app.controller('firstController', function($scope, $anchorScroll, $location) {
    $anchorScroll();
    $scope.message = 'First Controller';

    $scope.goBack = function() {
        $location.path('/third');
    };

    $scope.goNext = function() {
        $location.path('/second');
    };
});

app.controller('secondController', function($scope, $anchorScroll, $location) {
    $anchorScroll();
    $scope.message = 'Second Controller';

    $scope.goBack = function() {
        $location.path('/first');
    };

    $scope.goNext = function() {
        $location.path('/third');
    };
});

app.controller('thirdController', function($scope, $anchorScroll, $location) {
    $anchorScroll();
    $scope.message = 'Third Controller';

    $scope.goBack = function() {
        $location.path('/second');
    };

    $scope.goNext = function() {
        $location.path('/first');
    };
});
```

And this works fine.

**My question** is if this is a good way of doing this or there is a better way?

Comment: You could use a shared service to do the logic and DRY up your stuff ($scope.goBack = routeService.goBack()). But there are a lot of options on how to achieve this, so i'd say that this is primary opinion based

Comment: @Sprottenwels can you give me an example how to DRY my code using service?

Comment: @Vucko do you have any plan to use path with parameters?

Comment: @wickY26 no, the paths will be just plain names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead **static solution** like giving path array in order, you can use `$route`...

so for getting routes dynamically we will use `$route`...

**BASIC**

just inject `$route` into our service and get all defined routes order by their order in config module... and define our goNext and goBack functions in our service

```
app.factory('NextBackBasicService', function($route, $location) {
  //array for keeping defined routes
  var routes = [];

  angular.forEach($route.routes, function(config, route) {
    //not to add same route twice
    if (angular.isUndefined(config.redirectTo)) {
      routes.push(route);
    }
  });

  return {
    goNext: function() {
      var nextIndex = routes.indexOf($location.path()) + 1;
      if (nextIndex === routes.length) {
        $location.path(routes[0]);
      } else {
        $location.path(routes[nextIndex]);
      }
    },
    goBack: function() {
      var backIndex = routes.indexOf($location.path()) - 1;
      if (backIndex === -1) {
        $location.path(routes[routes.length - 1]);
      } else {
        $location.path(routes[backIndex]);
      }
    }
  };

});
```

now we can **inject our service** where ever you want and call our functions with `ng-click` directive...

```
app.run(function($rootScope, NextBackBasicService){
  $rootScope.goNext = function() {
    NextBackBasicService.goNext();
  };

  $rootScope.goBack = function() {
    NextBackBasicService.goBack();
  };
});
```

here is [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/n3VGJvTyT2FJkUwTqFMx) of this example...

**ADVANCE**

instead of using simple `$route` properties you can **extend these object** which can gives you more flexible alternatives...

for example just define your route like this

```
when('/route1', {
    templateUrl: 'example.html',
    order: 1, 
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
```

now you can reach that property in your service

```
  angular.forEach($route.routes, function(config, route) {
    //this will give us order that we set in config
    console.log(route.order);
  });
```

you can define more complex structure with this approach...

Comment: +1 like your solution better, it will be more usable because I won't have to put the routes in the _array_ :)

Comment: @Vucko you can build advance structure by extend route object... I was thinking about a structure like linked list...

Answer (score 1):

A much better way to accomplish this is to have a navigation controller (or `.service`) with an array of views in your app and keep track active view.  `goBack()` and `goNext()` methods would increment/decrement the active view number as needed.  Here how you could do this:

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="NavController">
  <div ng-view></div>

  <a href="" data-ng-click="goBack()"> Back </a>
  <a href="" data-ng-click="goNext()"> Next </a>
</div>
```

**NavController**

```
app.controller("NavController", function ($scope, $location, $log) {
  var active_view = 0,
      paths = ["home", "first", "second", "third"],
      max_active = paths.length - 1;

  function gotoActiveView() {
    var view = paths[active_view];
    $location.path(view);
  }

  $scope.goBack = function () {
    if (active_view <= 0) {
      active_view = max_active;
    } else {
      active_view -= 1;
    }
    gotoActiveView();
  };

  $scope.goNext = function () {
    if (active_view >= max_active) {
      active_view = 0;
    } else {
      active_view += 1;
    }
    gotoActiveView();
  }

});
```

Here is an working plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/kd8nyHBWDg6JqHoeXg5l?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

could i suggest you to use the ui router module? it have a little bit of functions that can help you, for example $state.go('state that you want'), essentially the states are similar to the view. Take a look [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

with the $state.go bind to you forward or the backward you can go from a state to another

here the [plunker with the states](http://plnkr.co/edit/7EYLJCpAE6XYo5EhslC7?p=preview)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle using the ui router module?